# How to add firebase custom claims without admin SDK?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I am developing a Android app with firebase as backend. I heard about firebase admin SDK but I don't know how to create it. I am using firebase console in web interface.
Now how can I set customer claims for a user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot. You could add custom claims from your local computer instead of Cloud functions or run a node process locally if you just need to add claims for a few users but the Admin SDK is necessary.

Checkout [Firebase Custom Claims without Cloud Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68327600/firebase-custom-claims-without-cloud-functions/68327673#68327673) for detailed explanation on setting up admin sdk locally. You could just locally run functions or a node process to add claims as mentioned in there.

Comment: Can you please tell me where to create admin SDK? I mean do I need to create it in cloud functions or some where else?

Comment: @RealTechHacks you install it using npm. `npm install firebase-admin`. Just follow the answer and you'll know ;)