# Firebase :: Create first user with roles

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

My app can users with roles `OWNER`, `ADMIN` or `USER`, in decreasing privileges. An `OWNER` can create `ADMIN`s and `USER`s. An `ADMIN` can create `USER`s. A `USER` cannot create anything. There can be multiple `OWNER`s, `ADMIN`s and `USER`s. Once the users have been created with relevant claims, this all works fine.

However, I do not understand how to create `OWNER`s in the first place. Do I create a cloud function that, when called, would create a new `OWNER`? What if someone can call it directly and create new `OWNER`s? How do I accomplish this?

Comment: No Alex. I was looking for a secure way to initialize blank database with the role with the highest privilege, since each role can only create less privileged roles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just run a NodeJS script locally to add that one time role to a single user. You don't necessarily need Cloud Function but using it will save some time in setting up service account. Just use the Functions emulator locally by writing a one time function.

I have a detailed answer on that here: [Firebase Custom Claims without Cloud functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68327673/13130697)

Once you add the `OWNER` claim, then you can deploy the same function to add claims to other users but just add a simple `if` statement to check if the caller has `OWNER` role or any role that can add the relevant roles.